# monitoring GPIO using udev library

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-device-driver, gpio, udev

currently i'm working on GPIO.I have two threads ,one to monitor the pin transitions on GPIO and the other to monitor GPIO for connection and removal to PC.I'm getting the device name from monitor thread when GPIO is connected to PC and Opening the device file in first thread and reading pin values.When device is removed ,I'm stoping the first thread and waiting for device to be connected.I'm using a flag for that purpose.

The problem is when GPIO is removed ,the first thread is trying to read pin values and failing as the flag taking time to reflect when it is changed in monitor thread.I tried with increase in sleep but its not reliable.

Is there any way,that the flag reflect instantly in first thread when it is changed in monitor thread .Any help is appreciated.

Comment: instead of checking monitor task flag, why cant u check the physical status before reading the value in thread1 ?

Comment: i tried that checking the existence of file,before reading or writting with access system call. The problem is when gpio is disconnected ,any pin set to high is changed to low .I'm unable to understand this behaviour?